# Javascript style.background not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am making a game with Javascript which requires users to flip cards. I am having a problem with the `style.background` property. It is working fine in Chrome but not in IE.

Here is the piece of code in question:

```
function flipBack() { 
    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
    tile_1.style.background = "url('Images/tile_bg.png') no-repeat";
    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
    tile_2.style.background = "url('Images/tile_bg.png') no-repeat";
    tile_2.innerHTML = "";
    memory_values = [];
    memory_tile_ids = [];
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try with add class, [tile_1.className += ' background';]

Answer (score 2):

Use **background-image**. IE supports this syntax.

```
function flipBack() { 
    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
    tile_1.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/tile_bg.png') no-repeat";
    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
    tile_2.style.backgroundImage = "url('Images/tile_bg.png') no-repeat";
    tile_2.innerHTML = "";
    memory_values = [];
    memory_tile_ids = [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a best practice to not use the shorthand versions for CSS props in js as the behavior is not consistent across all the browsers as some like Chrome do accept declarations to set individual properties while some like FF don't.

So, you could use the long hand versions such as `backgroundColor`, `backgroundRepeat` ..etc, or better go the CSS route instead and write your declarations and just insert the hooks in your code to reference them.